# TSQL - perform code for each row of an select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible somehow to execute some code for each row of an select without using a cursor?

In my case:
I'm having a temp table to store some data for a complexe script. At the end i want to pint some informations of this table (limited by some conditions) to the output.

Currently I'm using a cursor with a select to limit the rows of the table. In this cursor I'm using

```
 print '...'
```

to generate the output.

There must be an easier way to do such things...

edit:

```
create table #tmpAttributes(AttributeId uniqueidentifier, Value float, ValueString nvarchar(max), ActionId uniqueidentifier)

insert into #tmpAttributes (AttributeId, Value, ValueString, ActionId)
    select ID,..... -- in this select i'm doing some value conversions, if conversion is not possible i'm using -1

insert into ActionAttribute (ActionDefinitionID, Discriminator, ID, ReferredActionID, ValueDate, ValueListID, ValueMoney, ValueString, ValueUserID)
    select @defId, 'ActionAttributeMoneyEntity', NEWID(), ActionId, null, null, Value, null, null from #tmpAttributes

-- afterwards there is this cursor where I'm printint all rows where Value = -1
```

Comment: Not enough information. What are you actually trying to achieve? If you give us the complete scenario you might find that there's a completely set-based way of doing what you require.

Comment: Why don't you just put one extra identity column on the 'temp table' you have already created and loop for each row.

Comment: If you just want to print those informations "at the end" why do you need a cursor then?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to `PRINT` the rows instead of just doing a `SELECT` on all the rows where `Value = -1`?

Comment: I want to generate a output for the user to show him where the conversion failed. But you are right... this could be a select also -.-

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Executing a print statement for each row in a result set pretty much requires a cursor or an approach similar to this

```
declare @id int, @stuff varchar(20)
declare @tmp table
(
  id int not null
, stuff varchar(20)

  primary key(id)
)

insert @tmp
select id, stuff from mastertable
where condition1 > condition2

select top 1 @id=id, @stuff=stuff from @tmp

while (@@rowcount > 0)
begin
  print @stuff
  delete from @tmp where id=@id
  select top 1 @id=id, @stuff=stuff from @tmp
end
```

You are still looping thru each row, but you avoid a cursor. Since you are using a table var you instead of a cursor you avoid table locking, but this is not necessarily a better approach. You can process row by row in a variety of possible ways such as adding an "processed column" or numbering all of the selected rows 1..n and iterating based on the rownumber

You can only avoid row by row processing if you can perform a set-based operation. There is not enough information in your question to see if this is avoidable in TSQL

Now, writing a CLR proc may be more flexible as you have a much richer programming model, and there is little overhead to looping through each row of the result set within the CLR proc. Making a database call from the CLR proc for each row that a database call from each row in TSQL

EDIT - I see someone already added one possible way to convert you print statements into a set oriented operation. i.e.

```
declare @msg varchar(max)
select @msg = ''

select msg = @msg + stuff 
from mastertable where condition1 > condition2

print @msg
```

This is OK, in fact optimal what I was referring to when I said performing a set operation. A set based operation is always preferred when possible . It may not be obvious, but string concatenation can also get very slow in this example too if many rows are involved.

---

I said that using a temp var avoids table locking. This is not precisely true as sql server does write temp vars to a table in tempdb. What I really meant was that you avoid locking a production table and since you are guaranteed to be the only user of this table, you don't compete for concurrent access.

I also made no attempt to make optimize this. For example, the inner loop could track the id and the where condition becomes where id>@id (you will also want a primary key defined on id). Since the temp table is not updated during each loop iteration I would expect it to be faster.

Comment: Still a loop but without using the "heavy" cursor. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I think you need to provide more detail, but you might be looking for something like:

```
declare @msg varchar(max)='';

select @msg = @msg + 'Output line: ' + ColumnA + ' -- ' + 'ColumnB' + char(13)+char(10)
from #temp
where ...
;

print @msg;
```

Comment: So for each row the value of the variable will be extended... nice idea!

Comment: Make sure to add 'OPTION (MAXDOP 1)' to prevent parallelism, that will give unexpected results.